# Where is the documentation for the chrome extension API tab method, "getSelected"?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser-tab

So I'm creating my first chrome extension and was extremely confused for a while as I could not figure out how to grab the url of the currently open tab, until some research pointed me in the direction of chrome.tabs.getSelected(). The problem is, I cannot find anything in the API docs on this method. I've even found links to where it's supposed to be (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-getSelected) but it's not there. Am I missing something? Is this method deprecated and supposed to be replaced with something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chrome.tabs.getSelected` was removed in [release 16](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/whats_new.html#16).

> The methods getAllInWindow() and getSelected() have been deprecated. To get details about all tabs in the specified window, use chrome.tabs.query() with the argument {'windowId': windowID}. To get the tab that is selected in the specified window, use chrome.tabs.query() with the argument {'active': true}.

The documentation for `chrome.tabs.query` is [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-query).

Answer (score 5):

you should switch

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){...});
```

with

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow:true,active:true}, function(tabs){tab=tabs[0];...});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should switch

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function() {...} );
```

with

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function() {...} );
```